# how to calculate antiderivative $\frac{-3}{2t}$

Tags: calculus, integration

It has been a long time since I took calculus. How would you calculate anti-derivative of $-\frac{3}{2t}$? Is it $\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}$?

Step-by-step solution would be helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: can you guys give me couple of more minus signs for being so stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**
What is the derivative of $(-3/2) * ln(t)$

Comment: oops... so if we take out (−3/2) to the side we would have 1/t which I didn't see...it would be (−3/2)∗ln(t) + C ?